# how to add shipping charges by date in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to make an option if the customer want same day delivery the delivery charges will be $10 else it will be standard charges. just want to add check-box for same day delivery.i have that much information only, if someone can help I would be really happy since its been tough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have passed deliveryDate in request shipping object.

If we consider code of flat rate.Then in below function
 public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)

```
    {
If($request->Deliverydate  == Today )// replace code for getting today
{
ShippingPrice=10;
}
elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
            $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }
```

Comment: can you tell me in detail since I am new to magento. I haven't passed the delivery date yet, there is only standard charges for now.